# rviz shows the robot's location differently from gazebo

Tags: localization, gazebo, navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been learning how to use simulation tools, and now trying to use both gazebo and rviz together.

In the tutorial "[Simulating the 2dnav Stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_2dnav_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20the%202dnav%20Stack)", it seems gazebo and rviz work as expected when I use `pr2-armless-wg-fake_localization.launch`, however, when `pr2-wg-amcl.launch` is in use, rviz shows the robot at the corner of the entire field even though the robot is located at the center on gazebo.

My guess is that localization is not working properly since other launch files in the same tutorial folder with `fake_localization` in their file names work, whereas other amcl files don't either. I'm looking into each launch file but if someone could give direct solutions, that'd be great.

Env) Ubuntu 10.10, diamondback

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11029/rviz-shows-the-robot%27s-location-differently-from-gazebo/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just as in the real world, when using amcl, you need to [localize the robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack#A2D_Pose_Estimate) first by giving it an initial pose.  Also take a look at the [amcl localization notes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide#Localization).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-26**:
@hsu thanks. Once I figure out how to run the tutorial above, I'll mark your answer, and also update the wiki page.